SvelteKit goto keeps executing code after
On the client side, I send a JWT to the backend API for certain requests. If there is some issue with the JWT or it's not refreshed, I want to cancel everything and direct the user to the sign-in page.
async getData() {
    const authHeaders = await this.getHeaders();

    if (authHeaders === null) {
        await goto('/sign-in');
        throw new Error('Goto failed');
    }
                
    ...
}

My understanding is that the throw new Error('Goto failed'); line would not be reached, but I am noticing that exception come up and wondering how this could happen?
Using SvelteKit 2.5.7
Originally, I didn't have the await in front of goto and added that in. I added in the throw new Error just to make sure code after the goto was being reached. I've looked through svelte documentation and don't see this issue mentioned

It's not an issue, this works as intended.
Unless the client-side router is explicitly disabled, goto performs a client-side navigation, i.e. just loading in necessary code and data on the fly. There is no full page load, so code just continues executing.
Just return or throw an execption depending on context if you don't want anything else executing after navigation.
